# Несколько видео воспроизводятся одновременно, при нажатии на кнопку первого видео

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, функции, видео

На странице есть несколько новостных видео. Воспроизведение первого и остальных видео производится при нажатии на кнопку первого видео, закрытие видео так же работает только на первом видео. Остальные кнопки воспроизведения ни на что не влияют. Выполнено так, потому что частично этот код реализован для главной страницы.
в файле js какая-то путаница, но работающая как надо. 
Не получается сделать так, чтобы каждая кнопка воспроизведения и закрытия соответствовала каждому видео. Изменение id для каждого видео не помогло, всё остается так же.

Я не работала никогда с видео и возникли сложности, помогите, пожалуйста.

[image: HTML]

[image: JS][image: Как выглядит в общем]

Comment: Вставьте код не картинкой, а текстом в сам вопрос, так будет гораздо лучше. Для редактирования вопроса надо нажать кнопку "править" под вопросом.

Comment: да, код вставлять надо текстом, это полезно для тех кто ищет ответ на такой же вопрос, для них же и для лучшей читабельности лучше вставлять не весь код, а ключевые фрагменты; а рабочий код лучше залинковать в песочнице типа jsfiddle.net ну или в общем случае смотря на чем код полный список песочниц см. https://fiddles.io/

Answer (score 1):

На странице используется несколько id news_video, необходимо использовать класс вместо id.

```
<div class="news_video" data-ride="carousel"> ... </div>
```

Теперь обработчик открытия по клику будет иметь вид:

```
$('.news_video').click(function(){
...
});
```

в самом обработчике текущий объект, с чем надо работать это $(this). Т.е. вместо $('#news_video) надо обращаться к $(this). Так же:

```
var video = $(this).find('.video-player').addClass('open');
var player= $(this).find('.video-player').find('video');
```

`document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]` следует заменить на `$(this).find('video').get(0)`

есть так же недочеты с appendTo, а именно добавление кнопок "во весь экран" и "закрыть" лучше вынести в сам html и сделать к ним отдельные обработчики, например, `$('.btn-expand').click()` и `$('.btn-close').click()`

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том что вы обращаетесь к тегу video, и не важно какие классы вы меняете. У вас в коде функциями идет управление всеми видео по клику на id `news_video`.

```
 document.getElementsByTagName('video');
```

Так же у вас в HTML несколько id `news_video`, **`id` - это уникальный идентификатор** который не должен повторяться.